# modify css color of unknown/unreferenced value (lighten/darken)

Tags: html, css

I want to lighten/darken an object via css like so:

`background-color: lighten(oldcolor, 50%);`

But I do not have the oldcolor value. How can I reference the object which contains this css class and get it's color value?

For example:

```css
.myclass {
  background-color: lighten(this.object.color, 50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="test" class="myclass">bla</div>
```

Comment: You'll have to use JavaScript. CSS can't access DOM elements like that.

Comment: There's no such thing as `lighten` in any CSS spec I've seen. Are you sure you're not using a preprocessor like LESS or SASS? There's the [`filter: brighten()`](https://drafts.fxtf.org/filters/#FilterProperty) but it's not very well supported, and is different from lighten.

Comment: there are css filters, like `filter: brightness()` https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan it does not need to be lighten(). I was just looking around stackoverflow how to brighten and found lighten. Since all examples had a fixed value I was not researching which I need because the main problem (apply modifier on unknown value) wasn't solved. the filter should do the trick though

Comment: If you found `lighten()` on SO then you probably saw a [**SASS**](http://sass-lang.com) or [**LESS**](http://lesscss.org/) function.

Answer (score 0):

Three suggestions come to mind:

1) use `opacity:.5;` in conjunction with `background-color:yellow` (e.g.)

2) use a [html color picker](http://htmlcolorcodes.com/color-picker/) to find the color and see the color variants and use the desired variant.

3) find out the original color using 'inspect' or by doing a print screen of the page and using the color picker in photoshop/gimp to find out the exact color code and then use that (with opacity or the original html color code in the online color picker to find a variant)

Hope this helps

Comment: To inspect, right click and click inspect at the bottom of the menu. On Windows it's Ctrl+Shift+I

Comment: Sure I can use a fixed value but I wanted to have a dynamic solution. Using manuall color mixing via opacity is a creative approach ;). I found the solution in the comments (filter: brightness(%)) more convincing.

Comment: @Wandang that wasn't clear.. sorry.. but yes you can use filter ... that's another option and better for a dynamic solution.. the opacity would also be a dynamic option but you'd have to overlay the text with a high z index or put it in a sub div or span with a different id perhaps.. just some thoughts

Comment: @Wandang here is a demonstrative comparison between HSL and brightness filters. You would think the appearance would be the same, but they're not, so be wary. I have used the same fixed color for comparative purposes. For dynamic purposes you would reallly have to get the colour using jquery/javascript and update the css accordingly.. https://jsfiddle.net/qzwqhpsf/